# Bounding Box Regression

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, bounding-box

I have approximately 100K X ray pics of dimension 1024x1024. Only ~970 of them have pre existing bounding box coordinates. I am training the model on 70:30 training and testing ratio. My question is, how do i train the model if the rest of the images do not have bounding box? Since I'm no medical expert, I can't manually draw a bounding box around the image. There are 14 classes and it gets really difficult to draw bounding box manually

Comment: I don't think there is way around this - you either make do with what you have or get a medical expert to annotate more. You could train a model on what you have and produce predictions to somewhat make the tasks easier (maybe?) but this would bias the annotations

Comment: Yeah, I will try training the model only on the annoted images. Let's see how this goes. Good thing is training set is labelled. At least, I will be able to classify them if not drawing a box

Answer (score 0):

If you have a knowledge about the remaining not labelled images, for example if you know if an image has a particular class you can use weakly supervised learning to train image detection on all of them